# Adding another small Design with curve on the bottom of circle

Tags: css

[image]

I made a design of an ovale shaped circle where one part has pointy end attached to a line. finally able to do that, but i been trying to add another curve on the bottom with text in it.(as shown in pic attached)

so far, i came this far::

```
.link{
list-style:none;
padding:0;
}

/*.link li{
display: inline-block;
}*/

.link li + li{
margin-left:-30px;
}

.link li {
    background:lightgreen;
    margin-right:40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:-2px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    border: 3px solid #FF9900;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
    border-top-left-radius: 80px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    }


<ul class="link" >                      
     <a href="usercouponunlock.php" ><li ><strong> text#1</strong></li></a>
 </ul>
```

The above code, gives me the ovale shaped circle with pointy end and so, but it isn't giving me the bottom curve.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using the `:after` psuedo-class?

like so:

```
.link li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    height: 140px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-color: yellow;
    line-height: 240px;
    content: "text #2 ";
    background:transparent;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:-2px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
    border-top-left-radius: 80px;
    width: 110px;
   }
```

and adding `position: relative;` to your `.link li`?

see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OLKggWS4j8KryQOAtxWE?p=preview)

of course you can change sizes or whatever you like

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like a charm.. But actually i m trying to add a link to that "text#2" .. since it is not in body, how can i perform that..?

Comment: well, in that case you can maybe use two `<li>` giving the first one a class, let's say `smaller` and the second one can be `bigger`.

and then `.smaller` can be like the `.link li` you are using, the the `.bigger` like the `:after` psuedo-class..

this plunker shows how: https://plnkr.co/edit/OLKggWS4j8KryQOAtxWE

BUT - the problem with that approach is that this works for only 2 `li`'s under the `ul` element and technically you could maybe wrap each two `li`s in a div to add the desired effect if you have more links, but strictly speaking, that's not conforming with the XHTML standard